# How to handle logging of null values in a Java Optional chain

Tags: java, option-type

Say I'm using optionals, and I've got:

```
A a;
....
Optional.ofNullable(a)
    .map(A::getB)
    .map(B::getC)
    .ifPresent(c -> ...) // do something with c
```

However, if for whatever reason, I want to log when B::getC is null (or when a is null). Is there some idiom for dealing with this?  I could do a bunch of nested ifPresent calls, but that is very verbose.

The best I could come up with was a FunctionalHelper class, which wraps some Optional methods and adds others to support logging (log4j):

```
private static final Logger LOG = //...
private static final FunctionalHelper FH 
    = new FunctionalHelper(LOG, Level.DEBUG);

FH.ofNullable(a, Level.WARN, "You gave me a null A"))
    .map(FH.logNull(A::getB, "b was null for a: {}", a-> FH.args(a.getName()))
    .map(B::getC)
    .ifPresent(c -> ...) // do something with c
```

It works, but feels a bit like a bolted-on solution.  Is there some idiom (or at least a standard library) for dealing with this kind of thing?

(I'm also wondering how to cleanly deal with checked exceptions thrown within the chain, but perhaps that's a separate question.)

UPDATE: In response to @Ole V.V., Here's the example with Optionals (UPDATE2: I tweaked it a bit to match log4j varags supplier semantics, but with functions:

```
private static final FunctionalHelper FH  = new FunctionalHelper(LOG, Level.DEBUG);

void foo(A someA) {
    FH.ofNullable(someA, Level.WARN, "You gave me a null A")
            .map(FH.logNull(A::getB, "B was null for A: {}", A::getName))
            .map(FH.logNull(B::getC, "C was null for B: {}", B::getName))
            .ifPresent(c -> { /* do something with c */});
}
```

Here's an If-else implementation:

```
void foo2(A a) {
    if (a == null) LOG.debug("You gave me a null A");
    else {
        B b = a.getB();
        if (b == null) LOG.debug("B was null for a: {}", a::getName);
        else {
            String c = b.getC();
            if (c == null) LOG.debug("C was null for a: {}", b::getName);
            else { /* do something with c */ }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd say the former is easier to read. Also easier to modify an existing Optional chain to add something when needed.

Comment: You know of `.peek`?

Comment: @ Thorbjørn  There is no  Optional.peek().  Perhaps you are thinking of Stream?  And I want to log when the result of the map function is null, so peeking before map(...) does no good, and peeking after map(...) won't be called if it is null.

Comment: Ideally, this would be built into the Optional api:

Comment: To be clear, I mean some sort of onNullMapResult consumer would be available in an overloaded map method, not  something specifically for logging:.   map​(Function<? super T,​? extends U> mapper, Consumer<? super T> onNullMapResult))

Comment: Ah, missed that.  My bad.

Comment: This is not what `Optional` was meant for. I think your code would be clearer with traditional if/else for null checks.

Comment: So far, I haven't seen a response that will actually work, or addresses the issue, which is that there's no easy way to see _when_ a null occurs in the chain.  So an ifPresent(...) never runs, but you don't know why. Unless you add in something like I'm proposing, that is. @Ole V.V. may be correct that it isn't what Optional is _meant_ for, exactly, but `map()` just specifies a mapping function, I'm providing a mapping function.  I just suggesting _composing_  it.

Answer (score 3):

Just as @Ole said, Optional is not meant for this:

Instead of creating an Optional, create a stream of a singleton
(I just noticed the existence of Stream::of).

You lose the convenience of Optional::map executing only if the element is present, so you have filter nulls yourself:

```
A a;
Stream.of(a)
  .peek(e->{if(e == null){LOG.debug("You gave me a null A");}})
  .filter(e->e != null) //Now you have to handle null values yourself
  .map(A::getB)
  .peek(e->{if(e == null){LOG.debug("B was null for A "+a.getName());}})
  .filter(e->e != null)
  .map(B::getC)
  .peek(e->{if(e == null){LOG.debug("C was null for B"+a.getB().getName());}})
  .filter(e->e != null)
  .findFirst() // Optional from now on.
```

In case you start with an optional, you can do:

```
Optional<A> optA;
Stream.of(optA.orElse(null))
```

The transition of stream to optional is smooth, optional to stream is not.

Comment: I'm using Optional per the api, and largely as intended,  The only difference is that I'm providing an Optional creation which defers to Optional, with a side effect.  To my eyes, what you are suggesting is considerably more complicated, and requires a stream creation, and a forEach where there's only one possible value.  You can't do a orElse or orElseGet, You have to rework the code if you started with a simple Optional and want to add a simple log message somewhere in the chain.

Comment: If having an optional at the end is a requirement, you can switch the forEach for findFirst, or findAny, which will return an Optional. If you have an Optional beforehand you have to break the chain of methods to change into a stream. I will update my answer.

Comment: Good point about being able to make it work with findFirst.  That said, while you can do this, I still think this approach obfuscates the intent, and requires extra code every time, and require rework if you started with an optional chain and you decide you want to add logging. Also, Streams are likely to be more expensive than Optionals.

Comment: I cannot comment anywhere else than my own answer because of rep, sorry for the inconvenience.

Optionals are intended to skip all execution if they are empty, and the creation of a null Optional (with Optional.ofNullable(null)) is actually an empty Optional.
In the code of Optional you can see that all functions start with: if (!isPresent()) return empty();
Streams may be more expensive, thats why they are useful for your use case, while Optional is not.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use such construct for two reasons:

1. First, you shouldn't mix and match `null` and `Optional`. `Optional` is really the replacement of `null`, api-wise. When you return `null`, then you have a problem. `A::getB` should return an `Optional<B>`, not a `null`. Okay, sometimes you can get API from the outside world, and you don't have the hands on `A::getB`, so if that's the case, you just get to work like this, but another way is to sanitize your inputs.
2. Second, you shouldn't log `null` values. If you log `null` values, this means that you have issues similar to `NullPointerExceptions`, and that means that you don't get what you expect. So this basically means that you should sanitize your inputs! It's okay to have this kind of statements when you're developing, but in production, you should be able to treat differently when `a.getB()` returns null and when `b.getC()` returns null. These days, it's usually better (because it's also easier) to use a debugger than use those logs about which value is `null`.

Both issues are resolved by sanitizing your inputs. Sanitizing your inputs means that your should map your inputs that aren't yours to something that is yours. The usual answer here is that there is code duplication: the API code and your code. Well, yes: there is the API model and your model, but it's not duplicate code: one is sanitized and the other not!

But anyways, what you expect is entirely possible with a simple wrapper. It's similar to what you wrote, indeed (even though you haven't shown the code), but I guess you already found the best way to handle this:

```
static <T,U> Function<T, U> logIfReturnsNull(Function<? super T, ? extends U> function, String functionName) {
  return input -> {
    U result = function.apply(input);
    if (result == null) {
      log.debug("{} returned null for input {}", functionName, input);
    }
    return result;
  };
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(a)
  .map(logIfReturnsNull(A::getB, "A::getB"))
  .map(logIfReturnsNull(B::getC, "B::getC"))
  .ifPresent(c -> ...)
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I already had:   map(FH.logNull(A::getB, "B was null for A: {}", A::getName)). The differences are that you aren't handling multiple loggers (where does log come from?), or arguments to the log message. And you provide no mechanism for handling a null initial argument (a, in this case)     RE: "You shouldn't use such construct".  Why?  If the reason is "Optional is not meant for this", then where does it say this?  The map() javadoc just says it requires a mapping function, which I am providing.  I'd rather use something standard, but there isn't one.

Comment: @mconner Updated. On the contrary: `Optional` is totally meant for this. It's the bigger picture that you shouldn't use.

Comment: Regarding "you shouldn't mix and match null and Optional".  The Optional.map() api is specifically for that purpose. Otherwise, there would only be flatMap().  The mapper may return a null.  And methods like Map.get  _will_ return a null if the value does not exist.  In an ideal world, maybe all apis are written in terms of Optionals, but there's a lot that's not. Optional allows you to _do_ that sanitation. But unlike an if-then-else ... I can't easily add a log line. Debuggers are great, but you can't always see timing issues.RE: logging nulls I don't see how that's similar to NPEs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Optional.orElseGet()` together with a `Supplier<A>` that returns some default `A` value (not sure if I have your types exactly right).

```
Supplier<A> nonNullASupplier = () -> {
    LOGGER.log("Invoking supplier because A was null");
    return new A();
}
```

Then in calling code:

```
Optional.ofNullable(a)
    .orElseGet(nonNullASupplier)
    .map(A::getB)
    .map(B::getC)
    .ifPresent(c -> ...) // do something with c
```

Again not 100% sure what types `A` and `B` are here but this is the basic idea.

Comment: You can't use Supplier<B> on Optional<A>.orElseGet, It will not compile.  And orElseGet(...) returns a T, not an Optional<T>, so it comes at the end of an optional chain, and the map(B::getC) would not be possible.

Comment: @mconner Okay now I think I understand your issue.  I was confused by your use of `A::getB`.  Unfortunately I don't think what you want to do is possible using "idiomatic" Optional methods.  Looks like you'll have to use a good ol' fashioned if-else here.

Comment: Well, Like I have in the original post, I have a helper class that does some of this.  Its better than if-else.  Just seems like there should be a standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fit you, but maybe you can use the Null Object Pattern.

```java
class NullA extends A {
  B getB() {
     return new NullB();
  }
}
class NullB extends B {
  C getC() {
     return new NullC();
  }
}
class NullC extends C {
}
```

And then using `orElseGet` to return the null object:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(a)
    .orElseGet(new NullA())
    .map(A::getB)
    .map(B::getC)
```

Comment: If there's no chance of null, then Optional is not needed.  Just do:  a.getB().getC().  In the real world, I've got to deal with a host of legacy classes (and APIs) that do not follow the Null pattern, and we aren't about to change them.   Also:  orElseGet() returns an A, here, so the subsequent map() calls won't even compile.

Comment: Just re-read my comment and realized it may have come across as snarky.  By "in the real world", I meant that _my example_ is somewhat simplistic, and in reality, I don't have the ability to change all the code.  I never meant to suggest that @matanper wasn't living in the real world.

Comment: @mconner it's ok, no offense taken. I agree this is less doable most of the time, just tried to accelerate brainstroming